# SpriteKit in iOS 8: should I cache my SKNodes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am writing an iOS 8.1 app that will draw bar charts. The user will be able to filter the dataset from which the chart is drawn, dynamically changing the chart.

Each chart will be composed of around 2,000 SKNodes (simple boxes). Every time the selection changes, the previously used SKNodes will be discarded, and an entirely new set will be computed.

I estimate users will not recompute the chart more than 20 times per use of the application.

I was wondering if it made sense to recycle previously used SKNodes, to avoid the cost of allocation, deallocation, and memory fragmentation, and their impact on the perceived performance, or, if for "only" 40,000 SKNodes it would be over complicating the software.

If caching does make sense, what would be an efficient Swift data structure to act as a cache?

Comment: that's a lot of nodes! Do a quick test to see if just the performance of 2-40 thousand nodes is in any way acceptable. Test on a (older/slowest) device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid building a cache until you have a measurable performance issue. If you have one, then make a cache.

If you have to build one, I would store unused nodes in an `NSCache` instance so they can be purged on memory pressure. You can follow the `UITableView`/`UICollectionView` pattern - dequeue a node, prepare it for reuse, set it up, and then use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am new to Cocoa and didn't know about NSCache.

Comment: I looked at the docs for NSCache, and it seems to require a key to be able to store and retrieve an object. How would you dequeue just any node, like with UITableViewCells?